# Width issue with the tabsetPanel function of the package shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, panel

I come here to solve an apparently simple issue. I would like to use the tabsetPanel function to make my panels reactive. But when I use it, a blank space is created between the top of my page and the names of my two panels.

Below, a reproductible example :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

tabBox(width = 12,title=htmlOutput('Date_Panel'),
     tabsetPanel(id = "AB",

                 tabPanel(
                   value = "A",
                   title = span(icon("lightbulb-o"), HTML('&nbsp;'), strong("A"), style="color:#FE5815;")
                 ),
                 tabPanel(
                   value = "B",
                   title = span(icon("fire-o"), HTML('&nbsp;'), strong("B"), style="color:#FE5815;")
                 )
     )
 )
)

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Date_Panel <- renderText(if(input$AB=='A'){
  text='title_A'
   }
   else{
   text='title_B'

  }

   )
   }

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When we remove the tabsetPanel function, the blank space is not here. I would like to use this function without any strange space.

Thank you in advance of your help.

Comment: Why are you using `tabBox`? If you remove that space will go away.

Comment: The point is that I want that my `tabBox` title be reactive to my panels, then I need to use this `tabBox`. But thanks for the trick

Comment: @SBista I didn't mention your name on my answer, sorry. Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: What do you mean by you want the " `tabBox` title be reactive to my panels"? Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand the functionality that you want.

Comment: @SBista, Do you see the title of my `tabbox` (that I called "title") ? I want he is  reactive to the panel on which I click. If I click on panel A, there will be "title A", if I click on panel B, there will be "panel B" for example. I know how to do it : just a `renderText`. But this space created by `tabsetPanel` ruins everything. I hope you understand better.

Comment: So you wan the panel selection of A and B to come in the same line as the title?

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the space you can remove the tabsetPanel from your ui code:

The modification in your ui code will be something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabBox(width = 12,title="Title",
         # tabsetPanel(id = "AB",
                     
                     tabPanel(
                       value = "A",
                       title = span(icon("lightbulb-o"), HTML('&nbsp;'), strong("A"), style="color:#FE5815;")
                     ),
                     tabPanel(
                       value = "B",
                       title = span(icon("fire-o"), HTML('&nbsp;'), strong("B"), style="color:#FE5815;")
                     )
         # )
  )
)
```

With this modification you will get output which looks like this:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Instead of having `tabsetPanel` you can change the title based on id of `tabBox`. Have a look at this code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      tabBox(width = 12,title=htmlOutput('Date_Panel'), id = "AB",
              # tabsetPanel(id = "AB",
                         
                         tabPanel(
                           value = "A",
                           title = span(icon("lightbulb-o"), HTML('&nbsp;'), strong("A"), style="color:#FE5815;")
                         ),
                         tabPanel(
                           value = "B",
                           title = span(icon("fire-o"), HTML('&nbsp;'), strong("B"), style="color:#FE5815;")
                         )
              # )
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$Date_Panel <- renderText(if(input$AB=='A'){
        text='title_A'
      }
      else{
        text='title_B'
        
      }
      
      )
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With this you get the desired output.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for yor help. But I need the function `tabsetPanel` to have an input to use in my server...How the title would be reactive then ? Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: I do not think I fully understand what you mean. what do you exactly mean by "to have an input to use in my server"?

Comment: I just modificated my example by adding the condition which changes the title. Just launch the application, you will understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mez13, have a look at the edited code. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: This works great ! I didn't know we can link an id to a `tabbox`, no need to use the `tabsetPanel` function. Thank you very much